# Getting a 404 when using .NET 4 on IIS 6, with or without MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, .net-4.0, iis-6, http-status-code-404, asp.net-4.0

I've completed this set up on a fair few IIS 6 boxes, but one is giving me a tough time.

The problem occurs when I add the application extension mapping to:

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.21006\aspnet_isapi.dll`

When this is in place, I get a 404 error on every request.

Even if I remove all files from the application directory apart from a basic `test.htm` and navigate to that, I still get a 404.

- I've unchecked the "Verify that file exists"
- I've set up a .NET 4 application pool and pointed my application to that
- I've changed the ASP.NET version to 4.0.21006
- I've checked the IIS log file, and there's nothing useful in there (it only shows the first bunch of requests after each reboot and then stops logging)
- I've checked the application event log and nothing gets reported
- I've installed MVC 2

I've copied the set up onto another box, just to be sure, following all the same steps - and it all works!

What else can I look out for??

**N.B:**

If I set .NET to v2 in IIS, then I can successfully navigate to `\test.htm`

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600961/error-running-asp-net-mvc-2-project-out-of-the-box-in-vs-2010

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go into Web Service Extensions in IIS and set ASP.NET 4.0 to Allowed instead of Prohibited.

Like this:

[image]

BTW: This happened to me in the RTM version of .net 4 as well, so it's not just the betas.

Comment: You also might run into Server Unavailable and will find this message in the event log:

It is not possible to run two different versions of ASP.NET in the same IIS process. Please use the IIS Administration Tool to reconfigure your server to run the application in a separate process.