# 404 error after deploying ASP.MVC3 website to IIS6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a 404 when setting up MVC in IIS 6 and using .NET 4 beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222999/getting-a-404-when-setting-up-mvc-in-iis-6-and-using-net-4-beta-2)

I have deployed ASP.NET MVC3 site to IIS6. I reinstall .net 4 and also installed asp.net mvc3 on that server. Added wildcard mapping as well c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll

My web site uses windows authentication using active directory.

I am not sure what is causing this issue. I tried almost everything suggested online. But no luck.

Comment: Sorry, it says " You are not authorized to view this page "

Comment: @kyle: I can not see your comment. Can you please post it again?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this guide, MVC can be a little tricky on IIS6.
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Also this post might have what your looking for. 
[Getting a 404 when using .NET 4 on IIS 6, with or without MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222999/getting-a-404-when-setting-up-mvc-in-iis-6-and-using-net-4-beta-2)

Comment: Thanks but I already referred this links. I fixed an issue. It was having old MVC3 installed. I re installed it again and unchecked anonymous access because I was using Active Directory authentication.