# Deploying a project to Internet Information Services (IIS) with .NET Framework V4

Tags: .net-framework-version

Not sure here , but i hope someone would direct to the right in publishing a project to IIS from visual studio.
I'm publishing my project in .NET Framework V4. and on IIS I'm setting the Application Pool of the site to .NET Framework V4 as well.

Now, for some reason when I go to the site link it does not work and gives the following error:

```
*Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL:* /
```

But when i change the Application Pool to .NET Framework V2  the site works but i really need it to be working with the Application Pool set to  .NET Framwork v4.

Is there anything i am missing? can someone direct  please?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your .net Framework v4 ASP is not registered.

open command prompt (Start -> cmd) and for 32 bit servers run the command

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

open command prompt (Start -> cmd) and for 64 bit servers run the command

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

And Check if all features are installed for IIS
[image]

Comment: Maybe this can be of help to [link to similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222999/getting-a-404-when-using-net-4-on-iis-6-with-or-without-mvc)