# "The resource cannot be found." ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC and Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-3.5, visual-studio-2010

I opened a solution in Visual Studio 2010 RC that I previously created using Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RC using the 3.5 framework.  When I tested it I received a 404 error.  I tried adding the [default page as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600961/error-running-asp-net-mvc-2-project-out-of-the-box-in-vs-2010) but got an invalid route error.

Anyone else ran into this?

Comment: That does sound oddly familiar.. I think I "solved" this by creating an MVC 2 project from scratch in VS 2010 and then importing my old Views/Controllers etc. I'm sure there's a better way though..

Comment: sh!t...don't like that answer ;-)

Comment: hey andlju, answer with that comment and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comment from andlju:

"That does sound oddly familiar.. I think I "solved" this by creating an MVC 2 project from scratch in VS 2010 and then importing my old Views/Controllers etc. I'm sure there's a better way though."